# Como puedo guardar varios productos en una tabla?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

estoy intentando hacer un formulario para agregar tickets de reparación pero nose como puedo diseñar mi tabla en mysql usando las migraciones de Laravel.

Lo que trato de hacer en este formulario es que por defecto se deben llenar todos los datos de un producto, pero existe un boton que es para agregar otro producto mas y ahi tendria que llenar los datos del nuevo producto tambien. Como puedo yo hacer para almacenar eso en mi tabla ya que la cantidad de productos que tenga un ticket va a ir variando segun cuantos se ingresen. Por ejemplo:

Ticket 1:

tipo_producto, marca, modelo, costo, moneda.

tipo_producto2, marca2, modelo2, costo2, moneda2.

Y capaz despues hay otro ticket que tiene solo un producto

Ticket 2:

tipo_producto, marca, modelo, costo, moneda.

Estos son los campos por ahora de mi ticket:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('cuenta_id');
            $table->foreign('cuenta_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('contact_id');
            $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('statusTicket_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('ptype_id');
            $table->foreign('ptype_id')->references('id')->on('ptypes');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
            $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brand_id');
            $table->foreign('statusTicket_id')->references('id')->on('estados_tickets');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('typeTicket_id');
            $table->foreign('typeTicket_id')->references('id')->on('tipo_tickets');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('idOwner');
            $table->foreign('idOwner')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('OwnerName');
            $table->integer('status')->default('1');
            $table->text('short_description')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Y este es mi metodo store:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    /*dd($request->all());*/
    $ticket = new Ticket();

    $ticket->cuenta_id = $request->cuenta_id;
    $ticket->contact_id = $request->contact_id;
    $ticket->statusTicket_id = $request->statusTicket_id;
    $ticket->typeTicket_id = $request->typeTicket_id;
    $ticket->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
    $ticket->short_description = $request->short_description;
    $ticket->description = $request->description;
    $ticket->save();
    Session::flash('success');
    return redirect()->route('tickets.view');
}
```

A este metodo le faltan campos porque nose como hacer para poder almacenar mas de un producto por ticket.

Comment: @BetaM ahi la edite.

Comment: Creo que no estás identificando bien lo que necesitas hacer, es decir no veo que tiene que ver Laravel en el tema del diseño de tu tabla, por ejemplo si sabes que pueden llegar N cantidad de productos entonces debes identificarlos como arrays en el front en el atributo name, así si llega mas de un elemento entonces iteras y haces los registros que correspondan

Comment: debes diseñar tu bd al menos a la 2da forma normal, busca como, porque si lo dejas como esta vas a tener inconsistencia en tus datos